# Unexpected bool value being returned

Tags: c#

I wrote functions that take an uppercase string and return it in lowercase which should match the pre-defined lowercase version in the list and `true` should be returned but I received the `false` message instead and I am not sure why.

the Identifiable class:

```
public void AddIdentifier(string id)
{
 
   _identifiers.Add(id.ToLowerInvariant());
}

//this method convert the string in List to lower case which is called in the constructor:

public Identifiable(string[] idents)
{
    _identifiers = new List<string>(idents.Length);
    foreach (string id in idents)
    {
        AddIdentifier(id);
    }
}

// the AreYou method just to check if the list has the string I am looking for

public bool AreYou(string id)
{
    return _identifiers.Contains(id);
}

// this is when I receive a false instead of a true when I pass in an uppercase string version of the pre-defined one lowercase on.
```

Main class to pass in the string. I passed in the uppercase "KHA" and it returned false despite "kha" existing in the list. Could there be something wrong with the logic

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{      
    string[] identifiers = new string[] { "kha", "fren", "something" }

    Identifiable identifiable = new Identifiable(identifiers);
    Console.WriteLine($"testing for AreYou: {identifiable.AreYou("kha")}");//return true
    Console.WriteLine($"Testing for case sensitivity AreYou: {identifiable.AreYou("KHA")}");//return false
}
```

The program could compile and run normally with no error. And lower case sample do return the correct bool value

Comment: "kha" is not the same as "KHA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool AreYou(string id)
{
    return _identifiers.Contains(id, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Basically if you want a non-lowered string to be able to match a lowered string, you need to tell the comparer that you want to ignore the case of the string.  Remember that these are two different objects.

Comment: can you please explain which Contains method you use? List.Contains doesn't have overload with comparer

Comment: you will need to include System.Linq

Answer (score 3):

if you add only lowercase words, you should convert test sample to lowercase as well:

```
public bool AreYou(string id)
{
    return _identifiers.Contains(id.ToLowerInvariant());
}
```

btw, for better performance use `HashSet<string>`, not `List<string>`

Comment: Your fix should do the trick. However, if you do not mind,  I would love to know why the string id in the method AddIdentifier does not work. It should be converted into lowercase and added to the _identifier list, which will be used by AreYou method to check for any possible match. Wouldnt the lowercased string in the list match the pre-existing one, thus, returning true?

Comment: What are you talking about? AddIdentifier adds lowercase. AreYou checks an Uppercase. Why should it match against lowercase?

Comment: @Fildor Pardon me for my limited knowledge, my thought is that the AddIdentifier take the string id argument and converted into lowercase and added into the _identifier list. The same list is being use by AreYou method to check for the id match. I would be happy for any correction towards my understanding.

Comment: What you say is correct. Your expectation is not. Uppercase is not equal to lowercase (if you don't equate case insensitive explicitly).

Comment: @Fildor I see, so despite the TolowerInvariant method changing the exterior into lowercase, the data types at its core are still 2 separate things, thus AreYou was unable to recognize the match. Thank you, sir, I have learned.

Comment: @Simplylmk What ? There is only _one_ data type: `string`. You are filling an internal list of `string`s with _lowercase_ strings. The "same" string in Uppercase is in fact a different string. You need to do exactly what this answer does: convert the uppercase input to lowercase, so you can test equality in the list _and_ have a match. _Alternatively_ you can use a case insensitive string equailty comparer.

Comment: @Simplylmk no.  You can ignore the case when comparing directly though.  See my answer.